# How do I configure my uWsgi server to protect against the Unreadable Post Error?

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

This is the problem:

```
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 535, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 344, in __next__
    output = next(self._producer)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 535, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 406, in __next__
    data = self.flo.read(self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 267, in read
    six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 265, in read
    return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 59, in read
    result = self.buffer + self._read_limited(size - len(self.buffer))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 47, in _read_limited
    result = self.stream.read(size)
UnreadablePostError: error during read(65536) on wsgi.input
```

My current configuration reads like this:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
processes = 4
die-on-term = true
module = app.wsgi:application
memory-report = true
chunked-input-limit = 25000000
chunked-input-timeout = 300
socket-timeout = 300
```

> Python: **2.7**.x | uWsgi: **2.0**.10

And to make the problem even more specific, this is happening when I process images synchronously along with an image upload. I know that ideally I must do this using Celery, but because of a business requirement I am not able to do that. So need to configure the timeout in such a way that it allows me to accept a large image file, process it and then return response.

Any kind of light on the question will be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the version of uwsgi and python you  are using.

Comment: Did you try to set `buffer-size=65536` in the configuration file

Comment: Does this happen for *every* request? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon No, I haven't tried to set the buffer size.

Comment: @Phillip This happens for image sizes greater than 7mb, sometimes even images as less as 5 mb.

Comment: Can you rule out the possibility that the error is due to a second request? Did you try reading the entire request body into a variable (or temporary file) first and start processing afterwards?

Comment: @Phillip, cannot rule it out. A log recently from the server: [uwsgi-body-read] Error reading 65536 bytes. Content-Length: 992197 consumed: 131072 left: 861125 message: Client closed connection 
uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT !!!

Comment: Well, in that case: Isn't it possible that what you see are simply requests users actively aborted before the upload was completed?

Comment: You can't recive a message if determine a bytesize( `0xFFFF equal to 65535` so max). Multipart data not a message !  Every message got `EOF`. You can't accept message if   reached to maximum byte size. Sentence and text are different(sentence=post_message,text=multipart_data).

Comment: You can only use python2.7 or can be python3.4 ?

Answer (score 3):

The error quoted in the description isn't the full picture; the relevant part is this lot entry:

```
[uwsgi-body-read] Error reading 65536 bytes … message: Client closed connection uwsgi_response_write_body_do() TIMEOUT
```

This specific error is being raised because (most probably) the client, or something between it and uWSGI, aborted the request.

There are a number of possible causes for this:

- A buggy client
- Network-level filtering ([DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) or some misconfigured firewall)
- Bugs / misconfiguration in the server in front of uWSGI

The last one is covered in [the uWSGI docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Chunked.html#integration-with-proxies):

> If you plan to put uWSGI behind a proxy/router be sure it supports chunked input requests (or generally raw HTTP requests).

To verify your issue really isn't in uWSGI, try to upload the file via the console on the server hosting your uWSGI application. Hit the HTTP endpoint directly, bypassing nginx/haproxy and friends.